# in terms of communication

Tags: phrases

This is the first time I reach out to my teammates. And I want to ask them how they like to communciate in the future, with email, imessage, groupme, etc. How should i phrase my sentence?

Comment: Are you the team leader or, if not, have you been given the job of establishing the communication channels?

Comment: Request their preferred method of communication or mode of social contact.